# Is there a limit to the amount of "pieces" you can place in the map builder?

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

I remember in Super Smash Bros Brawl, the game limited you on how much stuff you could put down in the maps you made using the map builder. Is that still a thing in the Super Smash Bros 4? I have yet to get it (or a Wii U) on the Wii U, and only have it on 3DS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit, which depends on the size of the pieces.
You can see the limit represented as the "weight" bar on the bottom of the editor:
[image]

[Original link to screenshot](http://www.gamecrate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/SuperSmashBrosWiiU-5.png)

Comment: Is the limit (in comparison) bigger than it was in Brawl?

Comment: It's difficult to compare, because in brawl you had to use pre-made shapes and pieces, whereas in Smash Wii U you can draw platforms yourself.

Comment: I guess I will have to find that one out for myself.

Comment: This video shows off the map creation pretty well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pbj46ApX380

Comment: I will check it out once I get on a computer that does not have Youtube blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can call a limit, is the weight limit. What it does is indicate you how heavy your level is - if you had enough ground, you could place springs everywhere and call it a day. So yes, there is a limit, but it isn't big.

Answer (score -1):

There is a limit, sadly, but Nintendo said they will update it so you can play other people's levels.

As for the newest SSB, there is only a few things and items to use at the moment which sucks.

SSB Brawl I heard the stage builder was better, with more stuff and also I think the limit was bigger.

The limit is kinda small for SSB4 at the moment.

Nintendo may improve this in the future though.